# degtorad vs deg2rad in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, toolbox, degrees, radians

Is there a difference between degtorad and deg2rad in MATLAB? Is there a benefit of one over the other, like speed (or some other metric I didn't think of)?

http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/degtorad.html
http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/deg2rad.html

Comment: See if the code is publicly viewable using `open(deg2rad)` and `open(degtorad)`

Comment: I tried and it threw an error, does this mean it is not publicly viewable or am I using the function wrong? >> open(deg2rad)
Error using deg2rad (line 11)
Not enough input arguments.
 
>> open(degtorad)
Error using degtorad (line 16)
Not enough input arguments.

Comment: oops, they need to be encapsulated in quotes: `open('deg2rad')` and `open('degtorad')`

Comment: Please share any insights (you can answer the question yourself). I don't have the Mapping Toolbox, but I'd be interested if there are any differences, and what these are.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for suggesting I check the licenses in use!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank-you excaza for telling me how to view the source code for both functions.
Thank-you hbaderts for telling me to check licenses in use.

Here is what I've found.

They are functionally identical. Here are the only differences I could find:
1. The bolded line below that states that deg2rad has been replaced by degtorad.
2. They use different licenses. deg2rad requires the map_toolbox, while degtorad does not.

***degtorad.m***

> function angleInRadians = degtorad(angleInDegrees)
>   % DEGTORAD Convert angles from degrees to radians
>   %
>   %   angleInRadians = DEGTORAD(angleInDegrees) converts angle units from
>   degrees to radians.
>   %
>   %   Example
>   %   -------
>   %   Compute the tangent of a 45-degree angle
>   %   tan(degtorad(45))
>   %
>   %   See also: fromDegrees, fromRadians, toDegrees, toRadians, radtodeg.
>
> % Copyright 2009 The MathWorks, Inc.
>
> angleInRadians = (pi/180) * angleInDegrees;

***deg2rad.m***

> function angleInRadians = deg2rad(angleInDegrees)
>   % DEG2RAD Convert angles from degrees to radians
>   %
>   %   **DEG2RAD has been replaced by DEGTORAD.**
>   %
>   %   angleInRadians = DEG2RAD(angleInDegrees) converts angle units from degrees to radians.
>
> % Copyright 2007-2009 The MathWorks, Inc.
>
> angleInRadians = (pi/180) * angleInDegrees;

**License Difference:**

> degtorad(180)
>   ans =
>       3.1416
>   license('inuse')
>   matlab
>
> deg2rad(180)
>   ans =
>       3.1416
>   license('inuse')
>   **map_toolbox**
>   matlab

Comment: Just to be _really_ confusing, the upcoming release R2015b of MATLAB is introducing new functions `deg2rad` and `rad2deg` into base MATLAB. These functions, their naming, and their location in MATLAB/Mapping Toolbox has historically been a bit of a mess. Hopefully they will eventually deprecate the `deg2rad` from Mapping, and the `degtorad` from MATLAB, and sanity will prevail.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm using 2014b so I think I will stick with degtorad.

Comment: @SamRoberts Just an update, my office just switched to MATLAB 2016a (never got 2015b) so I tested it and it no longer requires a toolbox for either function.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Starting R2016a, `deg2rad` is recommended instead of `degtorad`. See the note on the [R2016a degtorad](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2016a/map/ref/degtorad.html) page.

As mentioned above, starting R2015b, `deg2rad` does not require a toolbox. Its [doc page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015b/matlab/ref/deg2rad.html) appears under MATLAB.

Comment: Which version of Matlab are you using? Thanks for the update!